# Rust data moved E0507 but I can't get the references working

Tags: rust, move

I'm very new to Rust and for an assignment I have to implement a binary tree called "SortedContainer". The problem I ran into is that the data moves somehow and I can't seem to get the references working.

The error code is [E0507](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0507). It occurs in "match self.root" in the insert function from the Sortedcontainer implementation.

Rust suggests &self but this creates a type error: he expected in BTNode::insert(foundNode, age, name) a Box but found a reference. The foundNode is now the error. Trying to derefence it does not work (*foundNode). The reason for this is that "move occurs because `*foundNode` has type `Box<BTNode<i32, String>>` which does not implement the `Copy` Trait.

Here is my code:

```
type ChildNode<T,U> = Option<Box<BTNode<T,U>>>; //Define alias (type); prevents recursive type (= self-reference), points to heap (box). Optional (option)

pub struct BTNode<T,U>{
    left: ChildNode<T,U>, //Box prevents recursive type/self-reference; points to object on the heap
    right: ChildNode<T,U>,
    age: T,
    name: U
}

impl BTNode<i32, String>{
    pub fn new(l: ChildNode<i32, String>, r: ChildNode<i32, String>, a: i32, n: String) -> Self{ //ChildNode very important, otherwise no unit. values allowed.
        BTNode::<i32,String>{
            left: l, right: r, age: a, name: n
        }
    }
    pub fn insert(mut node: Box<BTNode<i32, String>>, age: i32, name: String) -> Box<BTNode<i32, String>>{
        if age < node.age {
            match node.left {
                None => node.left = Some(Box::new(BTNode::new(None, None, age, name))),
                Some(foundNode) => return BTNode::insert(foundNode, age, name),
            }
        } else if age > node.age { //This else keeps the "name" from going out of scope
            match node.right {
                None => node.right = Some(Box::new(BTNode::new(None, None, age, name))),
                Some(foundNode) => return BTNode::insert(foundNode, age, name),
            }
        }
        eprintln!("Undefined/Unimplemented behaviour: age already present in tree. Failed to insert into tree");
        std::process::exit(0x0100); //Error code 0 on linux, 256 on Windows
    }
}

pub struct SortedContainer<T,U>{
    root: ChildNode<T,U>
}

impl SortedContainer <i32,String> { //Tree
    pub fn new() -> Self{
        SortedContainer::<i32,String>{
            root: None,
        }
    }
    pub fn insert(&mut self, age: i32, name: String) { //self is a keyword; self      cannot be replaced by say "tree";
        match self.root {     //ERROR E0507 HERE. If &self, then error below
            None => {
                self.root = Some(Box::new(BTNode::new(None, None, age, name)));
            },
            Some(foundNode) => {
                BTNode::insert(foundNode, age, name); //If &self, then foundNode has error E0308 mismatched types. Expected struct Box, found reference.
                           //If dereferenced, then error E0507 again.    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: this might be some relevant information. It is how I try using the SortedContainer and how I'm testing it.

```
fn main() {
    let mut tree: tree::SortedContainer<i32, String> = tree::SortedContainer::new();
    tree.insert(32, "Papa Johns".to_string()); //This works due to the self parameter in the function 
    tree.insert(24, "Johan".to_string());
    tree.insert(8, "EvaBeva".to_string());
    tree.insert(64, "PizzaLoverYesYes".to_string());
    tree.print();
}
```

Comment: Commenting out `pub fn print(&self) {}` in your code does not change the error - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=930d12c0dc3393fd7168fc985f0f715e. Are you sure you haven't changed anything else?

Comment: Keeping in mind that a binary tree is basically a set of linked lists with some elements in common, you should read: [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Comment: @Cerberus You are right, it removes all errors Visual Studio Code indicates, but it still gives compiler errors. The error is, however, again E0507. It also occurs in the same line, namely "match self.root" from the insert function in the SortedContainer implementation. I'm editing the question

Comment: The `None` branches in your `insert` function assign to a field but do not return a value, so execution will fall out of the `if-else` chain and run into your process-ending logic. (P.S. use `panic!("age already present in tree");` instead)

Answer (score 1):

When you deconstruct `self.root` in `SortedContainer::insert` and take a `foundNode` from inside it, there are 3 options:

1. either you take by value (this is the default, also called "move")
2. or you make a copy ("clone")
3. or you take it by reference

Case 1 is not what you want, because it is going to tear foundNode apart from self.root, and make it invalid, but you want to continue using self.root again after calling insert.

Case 2 is probably not what you want, because copying the whole subtree tree is not a greata performance.

So it's better to pass a reference. In this case you also need to adapt `BTNode::insert` to accept a reference (currently in your version it expects a value):

```
pub fn insert(node: &mut Box<BTNode<i32, String>>, ...
```

Comment: This is the right direction, but OP will have to change more than just the function signature for this to work. It'd be good to address all the required fixes.

Comment: This is not exactly the answer I was looking for but it does help me to better understand Rust. Thank you for that. I had tried a few things myself and my assignment partner found a fix to one of the trials/implementations. I have "self.root = ..." in the "None =>" but no "self.root = ..." in the "Some(...)". It was a logic problem after all